# How to login sftp remote server using python with .ppk file

Tags: python, remote-server

I'm trying to login the remote server using ppk file with paramiko but it says not a valid RSA key. I searched on web but not able to come with correct solution. Also I'm newbee in python so may be difficult for me too.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/519) GitHub issue. Do you have the same problem?

Comment: No! it says "*** AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.